# Default Argv argument types

Tags: c, full-text-search

What are the default argv data types?

I want to grab 2 arguments from the cmd line and pass these arguments to fts_open with the return being set to fts_read.  first being source folder path and second being output file path.

I previously passed argv + 1 and it sent the first argument, as well as the second argument, so the source and the output path was being included in the paths to traverse.

I only want to source path to be used for fts_open.

I know fts_open takes a NULL terminated list, I would like to create this from the first argument, the source. I had a few warnings before regarding different data types.

I just want to grab the first arg and store it in a char * and then create a NULL terminated list from this to pass to fts_open.

Comment: yes, but when I passed argv[1] to fts_open, it included argv[2] into the paths it was traversing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **copy** the argument in question to a new list that only includes that argument and the final NULL pointer

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) /* error */;
    char **copy = malloc(2 * sizeof *copy);
    copy[0] = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
    if (!copy[0]) /* error */;
    strcpy(copy[0], argv[1]);
    copy[1] = NULL;

    whatever(copy/*, ... */);

    /* ... */

    free(copy[0]);
    free(copy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to the title question is `char **`, but I don't think that's really a lot of help to you.

At least if I understand correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
char *args[2];

args[0] = argv+1;
args[1] = NULL;

fts_open(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `main` function has signature `(int, char**)`, then the second argument is the pointer to the first element of a null-terminated array of `char*`, each of which itself is a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated array of `char`s which represent the program argument strings.

You can print them like this:

```
for (char ** p = argv; *p; ++p)
{
    printf("Argument: %s\n", *p);
}
```

Or, to print them from the back:

```
while (argc--) { printf("Argument %i: %s\n", argc, argv[argc]); }
```